# Full text search issue in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using full text search in SQL Server 2008. If I did search with keyword `tigers wife`
it should be also return `tiger's wife` in result. Can anybody please help me for this concept?
Thanks.

Comment: Search for keyword: `'"tigers wife" AND "tiger's wife"'` or `"tiger* wife"` although the latter will allow any number of letters between the tiger and his/her wife

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

Assuming the table has both "tigers wife" and "tiger's wife".

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table
WHERE PATINDEX ('%tiger%', ColumnName) > 0
```

The function "PATINDEX" will look for patters matching the keyword and return 0 or 1 accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answer,
But it's take too long time there are more than 26 million records.

Answer (score 0):

Word tiger's contains noise word(not stoplist) 's. So full text search ignore 's and think tiger's as tiger while creating full text index.